# How to determine the context/xaml file for a converter

Tags: wpf, xaml, converters

I received an exception report from a production user that originated in the "Convert" method of an IValueConverter. I cannot reproduce this problem. This particular converter is used throughout our application. I want to be able to put exception handling into the converter so that I can capture the proper context of the problem if it happens again. From a converters perspective, without specifically passing in some contextual value as part of the Convert method arguments, is it possible to know from where that converter is being accessed? Which xaml file is it specifically being used in where the exception has occurred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to crack this I will suggest you to pass the unique `ConverterParameter` with every usage of your converter e.g if you are using the converter for binding the content of ContentControl in View1 you can do:

```
Content = {Binding Converter={StaticResource BensConvereter}, ConverterParameter = "View1ContenControl"
```

and in the exception handling code you can log this converter parameter. Whenever the converter will fail you will get the log of which view and which controls binding has failed the converter.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was afraid of. I was hoping there was a more elegant solution.